# check if nested dict is not empty as part of api loop

Tags: python, api, dictionary, nested

i'm a little stuck...

i am calling an api to get my trade executions but the function has pagination... so, i'm thinking i need to call at least once and see what are the total pages.. however, the number of total pages is 10000 seems odd as i know i only have around 4000-5000 executions and given the limit per page of 999, looping through all makes no sense..

So, I have the idea that i would like to test on each call if there nested dict is notEmpty and index the page +=1 and then call again. if nested dict isEmpty, i stop.

part of the CODE

```
try: getTrans = api_qr.get_my_executions(product_id=14, limit=999, page=1)
except jhAPIException as e:
   print(e.status_code)
   print(e.messages)
   if e.status_code==429:
     print("429 *** jh")
```

below is snapshot from the debugger.

[image: snapshot]

getTrans = {dict}{'current_page': 1, 'total_pages': 10000, 'models': [{'id': 45145692, 'quantity': '4545.0', 'price': '0.065', 'taker_side': 'sell', 'created_at': 1531388944, 'my_side': 'buy'}, {'id': 44881596, 'quantity': '1468.129', 'price': '0.07', 'taker_side': 'sell', 'created_at': 1531119691, 'my_side': 'buy'}, {'id': 44389650, 'quantity': '1434.34420319', 'price': '0.096', 'taker_side': 'buy', 'created_at': 1530559665, 'my_side': 'buy'}...... for example

what is the most elegant way to check if "models" is actually empty?

Thanks in advance

Comment: replace your image with text data

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. In this case, please include your code as text.

Comment: ok. will do the edit

Answer (score 1):

Your `getTrans` seems to return a dictionary and the one you displayed contains data.

Given that you didn't share what does the look like the solution is either:

```
if getTrans()['models']:
    ...
```

or:

```
if getTrans:
   ...
```